# WebSphere 8.5 Admin Console deploy vs AdminApp deploy (JAX-WS do not initialize)

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, jython

We have an EAR that contains a WAR and two MDBS. The WAR contains a number of JAX-WS webservices annotated with for example

```
@WebService(name = "QuoteService", targetNamespace = "http://quotation.my.place.com")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface QuoteService {
:
}
```

Our web.xml is web-app version 2.5

When I deploy the application through the Admin Console (file dialog select the ear, go through the 4 steps) the ear deploys fine. All the webServices are picked up via an annotation class scan I presume and are made available at localhost:9080/MyProj/QuoteService

However when I copy the administrative scripting command provided by the Command Assistance and attempt to replicate via a script using the AdminApp jython object, the ear deploys as do the MDB's however the JAX-WS webServices are never initialized?

I've attached the command provided. I noted that the -nodeployws flag is present however when I try with -deployws I have no success. Is there something else that kicks off the JAX-WS WebServices when deploying via the console?

```
AdminApp.install(workspace+"/"+earfile, 
'[ -nodeployws -nopreCompileJSPs -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary
   -nodeployejb -appname ' + appname + ' -createMBeansForResources
   -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn
   -noprocessEmbeddedConfig
   -filepermission  .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755
   -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED
   -nouseAutoLink -noenableClientModule -clientMode isolated -novalidateSchema
   -MapModulesToServers
[
    [ MyFirstListener-EJB MyProj-MyFirstList-EJB-3.0B.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
         WebSphere:cell=' +cell+ ',node=' +node+ ',server=' +server+ ' ]
    [ MySecondListener-EJB MyProj-MySecondList-EJB-3.0B.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
         WebSphere:cell=' +cell+ ',node=' +node+ ',server=' +server+ ' ]
    [ MyProj-Client-3.0B.war MyProj-Client-3.0B.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
         WebSphere:cell=' +cell+ ',node=' +node+ ',server=' +server+ ' ]
] -MetadataCompleteForModules 
[
     [ MyFirstListener-EJB MyProj-MyFirstList-EJB-3.0B.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml true ]
     [ MySecondListener-EJB MyProj-MySecondList-EJB-3.0B.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml true ]
     [ MyProj-Client-3.0B.war MyProj-Client-3.0B.war,WEB-INF/web.xml true ]
]
]' )
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this, the solution was with the 
    -MetadataCompleteForModules option. For the line

```
MyProj-Client-3.0B.war MyProj-Client-3.0B.war,WEB-INF/web.xml true
```

I had to change the value from true to false as the MetadataCompleteForModules indicates to the deployment manager NOT to scan the artifact for annotations as it deems the metadata complete for the module.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks,
Mark.